# Mysql SELECT com JOIN e LIMIT na tabela filho

Tags: mysql, join, inner, select-limit

Tenho uma tabela `catalogo` relacionada a outra tabela `imagens`.
Cada registro em `catalogo` possui N imagens.

Preciso que em um `SELECT` com `INNER JOIN imagens`, sejam retornadas apenas 3 imagens para cada linha da tabela `catalogo`.

Pensei em resolver a questão com algo assim:

```
SELECT c.`cat_id` as id, c.`cat_nome_fantasia` as empresa, i.img_nome as imagem FROM `catalogo` c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM imagens WHERE fk_catalogo_id=**c.cat_id** LIMIT 3) i ON c.cat_id=i.fk_catalogo_id
```

Porém a coluna `cat_id` na subquery  (`WHERE fk_catalogo_id=c.cat_id` ) não é reconhecida.

Sabem se existe alguma forma de mudar isso? Tipo tornar a coluna Global.

Então tentei:

```
SELECT (**@valor_id:=** c.`cat_id`) as id, c.`cat_nome_fantasia` as empresa, i.img_nome as imagem FROM `catalogo` c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM imagens WHERE fk_catalogo_id=**@valor_id** LIMIT 3) i ON c.cat_id=i.fk_catalogo_id
```

Porém o `@valor_id` parece não ter sido setado, pois não retornou registros.

Por fim tentei setar a variável:

```
SET @valor_id:=1;
SELECT (**@valor_id:=** c.`cat_id`) as id, c.`cat_nome_fantasia` as empresa, i.img_nome as imagem FROM `catalogo` c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM imagens WHERE fk_catalogo_id=**@valor_id** LIMIT 3) i ON c.cat_id=i.fk_catalogo_id
```

Nesse caso quase funcionou, buscou as imagens com `LIMIT`.

Mas, ficou preso a setar manualmente o `@valor_id`, ou seja, só busca as imagens do id setado.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: Na primeira `SELECT` tem `c.cat_id as id`. A partir dai, você deve usar o alias (id) mais a frente. Então ficaria: `... WHERE fk_catalogo_id=id LIMIT 3) i ON id=i.fk_catalogo_id`

Comment: Oi Rene, primeiro agradeço a colaboração. 
Tentei mas continua dando o erro tipo "coluna (id) não encontrada na cláusula WHERE". Tentei usando o alias (id) sozinho e com c.id. O campo (id) só não é reconhecido no WHERE do SELECT. Fora da subquery ele é reconhecido normalmente usando ou não o alias. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Bem pessoal **consegui uma solução simples**, que não é exatamente o que procurava, 
mas *dá para quebrar um galho*.
*Continua em aberta* a busca por uma solução usando (**LIMIT**) dentro do **JOIN**.

Situação:
Uso de 2 tabelas relacionadas 1:n onde temos vários imóveis na primeira tabela e cada imóvel possui várias imagens em outra tabela.
**Objetivo:** Retornar apenas 5 imagens para cada imóvel em um **SELECT** com **JOIN**.

**Solução provisória:**
Ter na tabela imagens, além dos campos como (id, fk_id_imovel, nome_img, diretorio), 
um campo ordem_imgs que deverá ser populado com números sequências iniciando no 1.
**Assim no SELECT ficaria algo do tipo:**

SELECT i.*, img.* FROM imoveis i
**LEFT JOIN** imagens img ON img.fk_id_imovel=i.id **AND img.ordem_imgs <=5**